# [Optimizing]Appending Numbers from a list with delimeters

Tags: python, list, optimization, while-loop

So I am working on a piece of code, and I am trying to find out the most efficient and fastest method to split the list into the numbers I need.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
eq=[' ', '1', '.', '3', '3', '5', '9', '2', '0', 'e', '0', '6', ' ', '4', '.', '0', '2', '0', '7', '4', '9', 'e', '0', '1']
coeff=[]
i=0
while i < len(eq)-1:
    temp=""
    if eq[i]==' ':
        for x in range(i+1,len(eq)):
            if eq[x]== ' ':
                break
            else:
                temp+=eq[x]
        coeff.append(float(temp))
        i=x
    print coeff
```

This does give me the desired result, which is `[1335920.0, 40.20749]`, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Please note that the numbers are coming from R, and as such, I cannot guarantee they will be in exactly the same format all the time, so slicing the list is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: eq = [' ', '1', '.', '3', '3', '5', '9', '2', '0', 'e', '0', '6', ' ', '4', '.', '0', '2', '0', '7', '4', '9', 'e', '0', '1']

In [2]: map(float, ''.join(eq).strip().split(' '))
Out[2]: [1335920.0, 40.20749]
```

Explanation:

`''.join(eq)` joins the strings from the list

`strip()` removes the leading and trailing whitespace

`split(' ')` splits the string by a single space

`map` applies `float` to each string in the list

Comment: Thanks alot. I forgot about the map method. Your explanation made much sense. I appreciate it!